# How to set the width of a layout in android that extends to a point relative to the right border?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout

I have a listview that has a small and a long textview (with varying texts in both) on the left and an imageview on the far right. Problem is that when the long textview gets too long it compresses the imageview on the right before wrapping into a 2nd line. Since both textviews have various lengths in each line, I cannot set a fix dp value for their length. What can I do that the imageview does not get compressed ?

PS: I create the rows in the listview like this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="45dp" 
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add android:toLeftOf="@+id/image" to your TextViews.  You may need to set the layout_width of the TextViews to fill_parent.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/info"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:toLeftOf="@+id/image"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:toLeftOf="@+id/image"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="45dp" 
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I added android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image" but it didn't change anything. The image on the right still gets compressed. And when I change the layout_width to fill_parent the image is not visible at all.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the ImageView was inside the RelativeLayout, give an id to the RelativeLayout and set the TextViews to be left of the RelativeLayout instead.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work. I do not really care about the relativelayout, I just want the 2 textviews with an image to the right and the 2nd textview not compressing the image.

Comment: Okay.. Remove the RelativeLayout that the ImageView is inside and try what I said originally.  Also, make sure the parent layout is a RelativeLayout